# Python3, Sum user-given tuple

Tags: python, user-input

Code:

```
def sum_given(values):
    s = 0
    for i in zip(*values):
        s += int(i)
    return s

try:
    v_list = input("Enter values to be summed.\n> ")
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid input. Counting as a zero.')

result_of_sum = sum_given(v_list)
print(result_of_sum)
```

Output:

```
$ ./helloworld.py 
Enter values to be summed.
> 1,2,3,4,5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./helloworld.py", line 13, in <module>
    result_of_sum = sum_given(v_list)
  File "./helloworld.py", line 6, in sum_given
    s += i
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

I understand this error, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

What I'm trying to do is allow the user to input a number of values, or a range, and have python output the sum.

I haven't implemented the range yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `zip` and the splat syntax here.  Instead, you should use [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the input on commas:

```
for i in values.split(","):
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> def sum_given(values):
...     s = 0
...     for i in values.split(","):
...         s += int(i)
...     return s
...
>>> v_list = input("Enter values to be summed.\n> ")
Enter values to be summed.
> 1,2,3,4,5
>>> result_of_sum = sum_given(v_list)
>>> print(result_of_sum)
15
>>>
```

---

Note however that you could use [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum) and a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to simplify your function:

```
>>> def sum_given(values):
...     return sum(int(x) for x in values.split(","))
...
>>> v_list = input("Enter values to be summed.\n> ")
Enter values to be summed.
> 1,2,3,4,5
>>> result_of_sum = sum_given(v_list)
>>> print(result_of_sum)
15
>>>
```

Comment: One question, do you type in all those ">>>" and "..."'s, or does SE put them in for you?

Comment: @NictraSavios - No, I use the Python interpreter and then copy/paste. :)

Answer (score 1):

A more pythonic way to do this is to replace the for loop with a sum() over a comprehension, generator, or map.

```
def sum_given(strValues):
    return sum(int(v) for v in strValues.split(","))

# output 15
print sum_given("1,2,3,4,5")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def sum_given():
...     answer = 0
...     for i in input("Enter numbers: ").split(','):
...         answer += int(i)
...     return answer
... 
>>> sum_given()
Enter numbers: 1,2,3,4,5
15
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> def sum_given():
...     return sum(int(i.strip()) for i in input("Enter numbers: ").split(','))
... 
>>> sum_given()
Enter numbers: 1,2,3,4,5
15
```